# Error while deploying jar to bluemix

Tags: java, scala, jar, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

When I deploy my scala app to bluemix, I receive this error during `cf start`:

```
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 150001, message: The app package is
invalid: bits have not been uploaded
```

I am using the next `manifest.yml`:

```
applications:
   - host: myname
     name: myname
     buildpack: java_buildpack
     path: target\scala-2.11\weather_sender.jar
     instances: 1
     memory: 512M
```

The `jar` itself is originated from scala,
I am using `sbt-assembly` and building a fat jar, so it should be possible to run it anywhere. I am able to run it locally.

**Update** Turned out that Scala **is** a problem in the end. It works unless I include a library which includes `scalaz`. Turns out that bluemix (or is it cloud foundry?) cannot process .jar that has `scalaz` included. Unfortunately I have no idea how to make `scalaz` work with bluemix. I could try to avoid using it as I do not need it directly, but in scala world lots of libraries have dependencies on `scalaz`, and this means that I cannot use any of those.

I also assume that the reason why `scalaz` cannot work is that it has very long paths (more than 256 chars). I've seen a problem when `cloud foundry` could not even upload `scalaz` if I unpack it from .jar

Comment: Can you try using forward slash `target/scala-2.11/weather_sender.jar`

Comment: @RamVennam Thanks for your tip. I've tried using just `weather_sender.jar` from the root, and it didn't work either. Please also see my update - I have figured some things out

Comment: @Archeg That sounds more like [a Windows issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows) rather than scalaz or cloud foundry.

Comment: @david Not that I do not agree with you, but it is possible on windows to query [longer paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094365/how-does-java-circumvent-the-windows-max-path-winapi-limitation) This is definitely a windows issue, but given that there are ways to overcome this and windows is not getting fixing that anywhere soon, I think it is responsibility of `cloud foundry` to work around this. Also `scalaz` could just not use that big paths. One of the requirements on my day job is to limit paths to 160 chars - a must if you have to work on windows